# Aggregation or cluster or hot spot

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, clustering

I have a set of thousands of tickets for clearing debris. I want to analyze clusters. I want to show all the areas with more than 5 tickets within 10 m of each other. How do I do this on preferably ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Buffer them by 2.5m with dissolve all option. Use multipart to single parts tool to explode it to separate areas. Intersect points with polygons, so you can find frequency of them inside individual area.

Comment: this did not work. I am not sure what you mean by intersect points with polygons. I tried to look for a tool to do that and nothing came up. Please be more specific

Answer (score 2):

You are asking a spatial statistics problem with the assumption that there is a clear solution in a specific software. You can look at the spatial statistics toolbox and see if there is available model that would suit your needs but, honestly to perform a valid analysis you are in need of a statistical software. Since you have a marked point process, take a look at [Ripley's-K](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/multi-distance-spatial-cluster-analysis.htm), specifying the `Weight Field` argument to account for your events, then figure out how to scale to Besag's-L so that it centers on zero. This will quantify the distance lagged clustering relationships of your data.

If you are just after a frequency/density measure within a specified distance, follow the advice graciously provided by @FelixP. 1)[Buffer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/buffer.htm) your data by a desired distance and, please read the help so you understand how the `Dissolve Type` argument will effect your analysis; 2) [explode the geometry](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/multipart-to-singlepart.htm) so that each polygon is singlepart (independent) and not multipart (grouped); 3) then intersect the points with the resulting buffer polygons using the [intersect tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm); 4) and, finally calculate some type of density eg., `d = [count(n | BID) * sum(n[y] | BID ) / area(buffer)]` where; BID are unique buffer ID's for aggregation, n are points and n[y] are the dependent values.

This density aggregation can be done conditionally based on the unique polygon ID that is assigned to the attribute table of the intersected points. I will leave it to you how to apply a attribute-conditional function to your data in table (perhaps in a different question after some research). Let me know if you would like an R implementation as, this is a fairly trivial problem and a lot less work (only about 10 lines of code) than what you will have to do in ArcGIS Pro.